# Value of a trigonometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

**Question:**

> If $x = \sin 1^\circ$, find the value of the expression: 
>   $$\frac{1}{\cos0^\circ \cos1^\circ} + \frac{1}{\cos1^\circ\cos2^\circ} + ... + \frac{1}{\cos44^\circ\cos45^\circ}$$
>   in terms of $x$

I really can't see how I would simplify this expression in terms of $x$. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: @MXYMXY Everything's in degrees. Forgot to include it.

Answer (score 3):

Hint $$\sin{1}=\sin{[(n+1)-n)]}=\sin{(n+1)}\cos{n}-\cos{(n+1)}\sin{n}$$
so
\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^{44}\dfrac{1}{\cos{n}\cos{(n+1)}}
&=\dfrac{1}{\sin{1}}\sum_{n=0}^{45}\dfrac{\sin{(n+1)}\cos{n}-\cos{(n+1)}\sin{n}}{\cos{n}\cos{(n+1)}}\\ \ \\
&=\frac1 {\sin1}\,\sum_{n=0}^{44}[\tan{(n+1)}-\tan{n}]
\end{align}